# AJAX search and JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to do some simple AJAX searching with jQuery and PHP. However I can't seem to get the proper search string to work. I want to search by title, and if the title hasn't seen set, just display all results when clicking search. Also I would like to show the results as beautiful HTML and not returned back in JSON-like-code. Somthing like:

```
    $book["title"]
    $book["author"]
    $book["description"]
```

SQL Set-up:

Table Name: books
Table Fields: id, title, author, description

HTML:

```
    <div id="search">
        <form action="#">
            <p><label for="title">Book Title:</label> <input type="text" id="search_title" name="search_title"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="search_submit" name="search_submit" value="Search!"></p>
            <p><em><small>For example A Game of Thrones or The Lord of the Rings</small></em></p>
            <hr>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="search_results">

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#search_submit").on("click", function() {
                var searchTitle = $("#search_title").val(),
                    data = 'title=' + searchTitle;

                if(searchTitle) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "getBooks.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(res)
                        {
                            $("#search_results").html(res);
                        }
                    });    
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["title"])) {
    $title = $_GET["title"];
}

if(isset($title) && !empty($title)) {
    $pdo_title = "WHERE title LIKE '%" . $title . "%'";
} else {
    $pdo_title = "";
}

$pdo_books = "books";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=removed;host=removed","removed","removed");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $pdo_books $pdo_title");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

Comment: You should user placeholders when using prepared statements, else it wouldn't be safe.

Comment: what exactly is your question? if it's about displaying json result in a pretty html, that's not a valid question. do you have an error with your code?

Comment: Yes, it won't search by title, it just displays all the data from books table when searching for e.g. Lord. Also right now I'm not concerned about safety, because I'm doing this on my local server and it won't be live, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its about formatting output in HTML from JSON, Then in your jQuery code you would need to parse json and repeat loop for each json objects in an array and add HTML to your page dynamically.

```
if(searchTitle) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getBooks.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(res)
        {
            var my_table="<table>";
            $.each(res, function(i, obj){
                my_table+="<tr> <td> "+obj.clumn_name+" </td> <td> "+obj.clumn_name2+" </td> </tr> ";
            });
            my_table+"</table>";
            $("#search_results").html(my_table);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried using the each-function you wrote, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to display the fields like obj.title, obj.author

Comment: That should work, try printing `res` on console and check error. `success: function(res){ console.log(res); ` . Let me know error message

Comment: The weird part is that I get no errors, the console log returns the JSON data just fine. I've even tried making another each statement outside my ajax call just to make sure I'm doing the right thing, and it works outside my ajax call, but the results from getBooks.php won't work like in your example.

Comment: I just tried to log the obj with the each statement and it says

`Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '481' in [{"id":"1","title":"The Lord of the Rings","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien"`

Comment: Hey, problem is with the response type returned by your php script. Its returning in `text/html` by default, but in jquery you are using it as a json so its giving error. You need to add `header("Content-type: text/json");` at beginning of your php script. it will solve that issue. :)

Comment: Of course. I totally forgot all about that, thanks a lot! :)

Everything works now.

Comment: Other way what you can do is parse JSON from string in javascript like, `res=JSON.parse(res);` it will convert string json to json objects. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned the method as post in ajax and you are trying with `$title = $_GET["title"];`

Try using

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
```

Comment: It has to be a GET request so I typed GET instead of POST in my AJAX call but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST["title"])) {
  $title = $_POST["title"];
}
```